# how do I elegantly format string in C++ so that it is rounded to 6 decimal places and has extra '0's or '9's trimmed

Tags: c++, string, formatting, string-formatting

How do I write a function that formats a string with decimals digits, without trailing 0's or unnecessary 9's?  Given that decimals is 2, here's what I expect:

```
0.999 -> 1.0
0.99 -> 0.99
1.01 -> 1.01
1.001 -> 1.0
123 -> 123.0
0 -> 0.0
0.1 -> 0.1
```

(negatives as you'd expect)

Here's what I have so far, but it's pretty ugly code.  Is there a nicer way to do this?

```
string toStrMaxDecimals(double value, uint decimals) {
    value *= pow(10, decimals);
    value = round(value);
    value *= pow(0.1, decimals);
    string temp = boost::lexical_cast<string>(value); 
    size_t dot = temp.find('.');
    if (dot != string::npos) {
        if (temp.size() > dot + decimals + 1)
            temp.erase(dot + decimals + 1);
        if (*temp.rbegin() == '0')
            temp.erase(temp.find_last_not_of("0") + 1);
        if (*temp.rbegin() == '.')
            temp.append("0");
    } else {
        temp.append(".0");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::string toStrMaxDecimals(double value, int decimals)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(decimals) << value;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    if(decimals > 0 && s[s.find_last_not_of('0')] == '.') {
        s.erase(s.size() - decimals + 1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: this is excellent!  If no one can do better by tomorrow, I'll accept it.  I knew it was possible to do this better.  Thanks.

Comment: I tested this, and it was close: 0.1 gives 0.10.  So, I merged your solution with mine-- using ostringstream to do the the rounding and stringifying, and my code to clean up the result.  Thanks again.

Comment: Nice answer, works perfect. Complement : not only <sstream>
but also <iomanip> must be included for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

sprintf is going to be far easier, more readable and more performance than C++ streams.  You don't need to do any rounding or trimming yourself.  Sprintf has flags for that.  You probably want something like

```
sprintf(targetBuffer, "%.2g", floatingPointValue);
```

Sprintf does the rounding in Java, and I'm pretty sure it will in C++ as well.

EDIT:

Sorry, the example code I wrote is for your example.  For your original question, change the %.2g to %.6g

EDIT:

Changed f to g to suppress trailing zeroes.

Comment: close, thanks, but it likes 2 is digits of precision and not number of decimals.
0.999 -> 1
0.99 -> 0.99
1.01 -> 1
1.001 -> 1
123 -> 1.2e+02
0 -> 0
0.1 -> 0.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using plain old sprintf to do the formatting?

It won't do exactly what you need, but if you round to one hundredths, and then sprintf the number as %f (for float) or %lf (for double float).

To round to 100'ths, you could do
num = num + ((int)(num-((int)num))*100)/100;

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'd like to produce the output I've got, which I think is pretty readable.  (A lot better than the user types in 0.7 and gets 0.7000000000003 or something.)  After browsing SO, I found find_last_not_of, which was pretty useful, so I was wondering if anyone had any other string tricks.

Comment: (also converting to int kind of defeats the purpose of using double precision numbers)